# Unable to coerce nested sized to unsized type using CoerceUnsized

Tags: rust, coerce

I am trying to use the functionality of `CoerceUnsized`:

```
use std::rc::Rc;
use std::borrow::Borrow;

fn main() {
    // Create (sized) i32 wrapped in an rc.
    let a0: Rc<i32> = Rc::new(0i32);
    // Coerce to (unsized) Borrow<i32> wrapped in an rc.
    // Works fine in Beta and Nightly cause of CoerceUnsized.
    let a1: Rc<Borrow<i32>> = a0.clone();

    // Create (sized) i32 in nested rcs.
    let b0: Rc<Rc<i32>> = Rc::new(Rc::new(0i32));
    // Coerce to (unsized) Borrow<i32> in nested rcs.
    // Does not compile in Stable, Beta or Nightly.
    let b1: Rc<Rc<Borrow<i32>>> = b0.clone();

    println!("{}, {}", a1.borrow(), b1.borrow());
}
```

[Playground](https://play.rust-lang.org/?gist=9dcce012ad3fc92814c2d47ec183bc0d&version=beta&backtrace=0)

But the nested coerce from `Rc<Rc<i32>>` to `Rc<Rc<Borrow<i32>>>` does not compile.

Why does `CoerceUnsized` not work recursively? Are there any workarounds, such as explicit casting?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Converting a `Rc<i32>` to `Rc<Borrow<i32>>` requires nothing more than adding a vtable pointer next to the `Rc`, and it doesn't affect the memory managed by the `Rc`. On the flip side, converting `Rc<Rc<i32>>` to `Rc<Rc<Borrow<i32>>` would mean stashing the vtable pointer *next to the inner `Rc`*. This would require modifying (and enlarging) the memory managed by the outer `Rc` (i.e., it would effectively require a whole new allocation). You could do this manually, but it's far beyond the scope of a coercion.

Comment: Is this essentially the same reason you can't coerce `Vec<Vec<T>>` to `&[&[T]]` — the middle item would require changing size?

Comment: Ok, you are right, the type `Rc<Borrow<i32>>` needs a vtable pointer somewhere. But the point is, the coercion of `Rc<Borrow<i32>>` to `Rc<Borrow<i32>>` does NOT result in the vtable pointer being on the heap next to the i32. In the case of a conversion of `&i32` to `&Borrow<i32>`, the vtable pointer is hold next to each reference instead. So i guessed, that the vtable pointers is always kept next to the outermost nesting level. And this would allow this type of conversion. Am i really wrong?

Comment: @Pentagolo No, the vtable pointer is next to the *innermost* nesting level (well, the innermost applicable level &mdash; `RefCell<Borrow<i32>>` for example is just another unsized type, not a reference next to which a vtable pointer could be stored.)

Comment: Oh, OK. So what is the first applicable nesting level in general? Is it the first inner level which stays the same size even if the inner type is unsized? How are structs containing potential unsized types implemented in Rust? Where is the vtable pointer located in 3 Nestes structs if they are potential unsized?

Comment: For me it looks like Rust would be a lot more flexible and strait forward if the vtable pointer would be next to the outermost nesting level by default. A special wrapper-type provided by the std-lib could force the vtable to be next to the special wrapper-type. An automatically implemented marker trait could indicate whether a type needs a vtable in its outer nesting level. Would this break any other existing functionality of the language or any existing code?

Comment: @Pentagolo Putting the vtable on the "outermost" location would break composition. Right now, it doesn't matter one bit how many other wrappers are around a value you're handling and how many of those layers you're ignoring by holding a reference to their contents. For example, if you start with a `Box<T>`, you can always create a reference to the inner `T` and it's the same as any other reference to any other `T`. And this special wrapper type and special marker traits would be a lot of extra complication for what seems an incredibly minor use case.

Comment: I would like to split the `Sized` marker trait into `SizeIsKnown` and `ImplsAreKnown` traits. A type which does not implement `SizeIsKnown` may not be passed by value. A type T which does not implement `ImplsAreKnown` forces its wrappers like &T to store the vtable pointer. If a type implements `Sized` right now it would implement `SizeIsKnown` and `ImplsAreKnown` in the new system. If a type does not implement 'Sized' right now, it would not implement either `SizeIsKnown` or `ImplsAreKnown`. The new system would allow for types which implement `SizeIsKnown` and not implement 'ImplsAreKnown'.

Comment: This works for nested unsized structs at the moment without any issue, why should it not work the same way for sized types. See https://play.rust-lang.org/?gist=ce3902de2e3796869f4e4c8ef469be58&version=beta&backtrace=0.

Comment: Right now the size and implementation of `&T` differs if `T` implements `Sized` or not. In the new system the implementation of '&T' would differ if 'T' implements 'ImplsAreKnown' or not.

Comment: And you could easily allow coercions of `Rc<Rc<i32>>` to `Rc<Rc<Borrow<i32>>>` even if `Rc<Borrow<i32>>` would implement `ImplsAreKnown`. This just would force 'Rc<Rc<Borrow<i32>>>' to not implement `ImplsAreKnown` and the vtable pointer stored with `Rc<Borrow<i32>>` would simply be ignored.

Comment: This is not a minor use case at all. If you have ever tried to write usable abstractions which include explicit ownership and lifetime relations for a bigger project you properbly end up combining the power of dynamic dispatch of traits and static data access of structs. See https://play.rust-lang.org/?gist=ea9f530244bce178a69817b0401a3f04&version=beta&backtrace=0 for an example. Things which work out great for static dispatch are unusable with dynamic dispatch. I do not see any technical reason for this.